# Suggestions on how to improve my "not constructive" question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, on-topic-definition, improvement

My question [Worst practices in C++, common mistakes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45138/worst-practices-in-c-common-mistakes)  was closed for being "not constructive".

Actually, my sole intent was to get answers that "generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise" and not "opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

I have edited the question and changed the vague term "bad things" to the word "pitfalls", which I hope is somewhat clearer. What other things could I change to emphasize that I'm not looking for subjective arguments in the answers, but real facts and knowledge which is truly beneficial to C++ learners, and thus make the question on-topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the first bullet point in the [What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) section:

> - every answer is equally valid

There's no **one** "correct" answer to your question - you are asking for a list of equally valid answers, and as such your question is not constructive.

It's a perfectly valid question to ask, but there are some kinds of questions that Stack Exchange is not suited to answer and this is one of them.

Comment: This bullet point is listed under "avoid subjective questions" which I do not intend my question to be (and in fact, I don't think it is). Errors are nothing subjective. And almost every question can have multiple valid answers. Isn't there a difference between http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/779/whats-the-worst-question-you-were-ever-asked-at-interview (which I understand to be off-topic) and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126723/a-free-game-development-language (which, among very many others, should also be closed if I understand you correctly)?

Comment: Also, in the given example, "every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”", there really can be no wrong/invalid answer since the question is about personal favourites, and that alone defies any further discussion. But there could of course be wrong/invalid/less valid answers to my question (e.g. things that are generally regarded as very elegant about C++). Hence, I don't think that this bullet point applies to my question.

Comment: @Felix I think that exactly is the problem, you are asking about personal favorites, that's not a question, it's a poll. What is the problem you are trying to solve? It's not that the answers can not be objective, is that there isn't one (or 2 or 3 but no more) correct answer to your question.

Comment: @Roc I understand now ... however, I think many interesting (and frequently, highly upvoted) questions fall into this category. It's a pity that the scope of the site doesn't include those, including mine.

Comment: @FelixDombek - it's not the site scope - it's the site (and network) "algorithm" (for want of a better word).